# wp_update_term: How could i update the "name"?

Tags: terms

I was just looking at wp_update_term and haven't found any possibility to update the "name" of the term. My scenario is pretty simple: I got some predefined taxonomy terms in a config file like this (just an example):

```
$taxonomy_terms = array(
  'taxonomy_a' => array( 'term_a', 'term_b', 'term_c' )
 ,'taxonomy_b' => array( 'term_d', 'term_e', 'term_f' )
);
```

Now i'm trying to update these terms based on their id. So if the id exists, i change just the name.

But here does my problem start: wp_update_term doesn't offer any possibility to update the name of term... Does anybody know of some work around, or do i just oversee something?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [`wp_update_term()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_update_term) in Codex you pass fields you want to override in `$args` argument, try passing `name` in there?

Comment: I remember using name in args to change the name

Comment: Works. In the meanwhile i checked the core code and found the description in codex beeing wrong. The decribed allowed values for $args is originally just the list of default values from core. It's allowed to pass any term argument, that may exist in a term object there. Thanks!